# How to avoid inserting zeros in dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, str-replace, zero

For example i have value in excel cell (37)%. With command

```
df2[cell]=df2[cell].astype(str).str.replace(r'\D', ' ')
```

I get value 0 37, but I want only to have 37. Any help?

The output of `df2[cell].to_list()` is

```
[3.04, -0.37, nan, -1.0, -0.44, -0.48, -0.25, -0.27, -0.59, -0.2, -0.09, 0.03, -0.42, -0.69, -0.04, -0.76, -0.66, -0.21, -0.53, -0.47, -0.1, -0.12, -0.47, 0.19, -0.21, 0.2, nan, -0.33, -0.06, 0.04, 0.44]
```

Comment: can you give the output of `df2[cell].to_list()`?

Comment: That column contains values in percentages and some values are in brackets and i want to erase brackets, for example if in cell is (37)% i want to have only 37

Comment: please provide a reproducible python object, a text description is too ambiguous

Comment: So output of df2[cell].to_list() is [3.04,
 -0.37,
 nan,
 -1.0,
 -0.44,
 -0.48,
 -0.25,
 -0.27,
 -0.59,
 -0.2,
 -0.09,
 0.03,
 -0.42,
 -0.69,
 -0.04,
 -0.76,
 -0.66,
 -0.21,
 -0.53,
 -0.47,
 -0.1,
 -0.12,
 -0.47,
 0.19,
 -0.21,
 0.2,
 nan,
 -0.33,
 -0.06,
 0.04,
 0.44]

Comment: Thanks, and now what is the expected output? For instance what should 3.04 be transformed into?

Comment: 304, -0.37 should be 37,-1.0 should be 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want strings as output:

```
df2['out'] = df2['cell'].mul(100).astype(str).str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
```

output:

```
   cell  out
0  3.04  304
1 -0.37   37
2   NaN  NaN
3 -1.00  100
4 -0.44   44
5 -0.48   48
6 -0.25   25
```

If you want integers:

```
df2['out'] = df2['cell'].mul(100).astype('Int64').abs()
```

output:

```
   cell   out
0  3.04   304
1 -0.37    37
2   NaN  <NA>
3 -1.00   100
4 -0.44    44
5 -0.48    48
6 -0.25    25
```